# How to upload a folder to a server - cpanel

Tags: html, css, file-upload, server, directory

I designed a slider through a free program and I am trying to figure out how to put it on my server. The instructions say this:

[image]

Step two is applying the html code in-between the body tags, which I have done.

The html is calling to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cssslidercode_files/csss_engine1/style.css">
```

I just don't understand how to add a folder from my computer's desktop into the server. What do I have to do?

Comment: You can use an FTP client (such as FileZilla) to upload files to a remote server.

Comment: @Quantastical I know how to upload files, I just can't figure out how to upload the entire folder or if there is another way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using FileZilla, a very simple and famous FTP (file transfer protocol) client. With it, you can manage and upload and download files/folders from your server to your computer and vice-versa. See detailed instructions for using [here](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Using).

Be aware that you gonna need some credentials from your web hosting provider, by default it would be ftp address, username and password.

Comment: You can upload entire folders to your server too with FileZilla.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use FileZilla or any other FTP programs,

Try zipping the folder, uploading it as a file and extracting it in the file manager.

Comment: This answer had minus upvotes for some reason when this is also a valid answer.